# Disabling included pictures in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am preparing a huge document with tons of pictures and Tikz drawings (based on Beamer package). Is there a command for NOT including all the pictures inserted by \includegraphics? This might speed up the typesetting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually the solution `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` won't work, because beamer loads the `graphicx` package by itself. You'll get the message

> Option clash for package graphicx

You have to pass the `draft` option to the package before it will be loaded. Therefore write

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
```

*before* `\documentclass{...}`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Or you could just call `\documentclass[draft]{...}` - it will do a few things more than just not load the graphics; but in preparation mode most of those are useful as well.

Answer (score 4):

Not related to `\includegraphics` but something that will speed up your typesetting in development mode: `\includeonlyframes`.  If you label the frames you're "working" on, you can typeset just those without disturbing the auxiliary files, very similar to `\includeonly`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\includeonlyframes{foo}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=foo]
    First frame
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=bar]
    Second frame, which will not be seen.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The beamer manual documents this feature as well.