# LaTeX detect image not found and replace with text

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use “default” figure if file is missing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39982/use-default-figure-if-file-is-missing)

I use LaTeX to take notes during my math classes. When the professor draws an image, I jot it down quickly in a notebook and include it later.

Currently I add a `\includegraphics{file}` line and then comment it out. This way the code compiles, but I still remember where the image goes. Sometimes, however, I forget to comment the line out.

What I would prefer is a command that looks for a file, displays it if found, and if not displays a message instead ("Placeholder for *file*"), rather than halting compilation.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could use the `[demo]` option to the `graphicx` package.

Comment: @PeterGrill sounds like the answer to me :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `[demo]` option to the `graphicx` package which will allow you to use the `\includegraphics{}` command with files that do not yet exist -- this will save you form having to coment them out.  Then once you have the graphic files you could simply remove the `[demo]` option.

Another option would be to use `\IfFileExists` to check that the file exists and use the `\missingfigure` from [the `todonotes` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes):

[image]

If you don't want to use an additional package you could just draw your own symbol to represent the missing figure.

### Further Enhancements:

- This does require that you specify the exact file name. This could be enhanced to duplicate the behavior of the `\includegraphics` package.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcommand\MyIncludeGraphics[2][]{%
    \IfFileExists{#2}{%
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
    }{%
        \missingfigure[figwidth=7.0cm]{Missing #2}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \MyIncludeGraphics[width=5.0cm]{images/EiffelWide.jpg}%
    \MyIncludeGraphics{graphicFileName.jpg}%
\end{document}
```