# Include graphic if the file is present

Tags: graphics

I am trying to create a latex document  that has a graphic: temp.pdf

```
\begin{figure}
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=30cm,scale=1]{temp.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

This works fine if the graphic file is present, however if it is not, I get the text:

temp.pdf in the document.

How can I switch this off so that if temp.pdf is not present, then latex simply ignores the includegraphics command.

Comment: Choose your duplicate: [Use “default” figure if file is missing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39982/5764); [LaTeX detect image not found and replace with text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69237/5764); [Check for a valid file before using `\includegraphics`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99070/5764); [How to check image exists or not?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95400/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine the command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\IG\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\IfFileExists{#2}{\IG[#1]{#2}}{\ignorespaces}}
\begin{document}

    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{somefile.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this, but I now get a blank page if there is no graphic. How can I remove this blank page?

Comment: How should I know what you did? As you can see in my example there is no blank page, if you run it.