# Can I test if a file exists?

Tags: conditionals, external-files

Can I somehow test if a file exists? And can I use this to do only things when it exists? I like to do something like

```
if(exist('members.csv')) {
 do something
}
```

Comment: See [here](http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?p=5047#p5047)    `\IfFileExists{file}{then-code}{else-code}
    \InputIfFileExists{file}{then-code}{else-code}`

Comment: An example invokation of `\IfFileExists` : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39982/use-default-figure-if-file-is-missing/39983#39983

Comment: If anything, the other question should be merged into this one.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since [the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39982/156366) is about a more specific problem that *happens* to have the same solution. In my opinion this question/answer combination is clearer if you don't specifically want a fallback figure to include when a file is not present.

Comment: @Circumscribe Reopen it :-)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
\IfFileExists{filename}{true-branch}{false-branch}
```

Notice that this looks for the file in all search pathes of LaTeX, so not only in the current directory, but in the `texmf` tree as well. Therefore, you can use it for instance for a "poor man's solution" when a package is missing:

```
\IfFileExists{upgreek.sty}{\usepackage{upgreek}}{\let\upmu\mu}
```

If you really want to search only in the current directory, you can do so by saying

```
\IfFileExists{./filename}{true-branch}{false-branch}
```

Comment: To add to @tohecz answer (I don't believe I can edit yet), I believe that if you want to restrict it to just the current directory, you can use this: \IfFileExists{./filename}{true-branch}{false-branch} and the `./` stops it looking in the other places.

Comment: This seems to have problems with underscores in filenames?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig That's quite possible, I didn't check.

Comment: What is the package here for `\IfFileExists`?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 LaTeX kernel. No package necessary.

Comment: You can also test the existence of a file given its fully qualified path: '/full/path/to/file/' on unix, or relative to the parent. `\IfFileExists` really means 'If I can read the file': `\IfFileExists` will execute the false branch if a file exist but you are not authorized to read it.

Answer (score 8):

The question was not limited to LaTeX here but the answer here is only usable in LaTeX. I add other alternatives.

At TeX primitive level:

```
\openin15=filename   % or \openin15=./filename for current directory only
\ifeof15           ... file does not exist
\else\closein15    ... file exists
\fi
```

You can allocate the input file descriptor (15 here) by Plain TeX macro `\newread`. It means tat more common is: `\newread\testfile`, `\openin\tesfile=filename` and `\ifeof\testfile`.

The main point is that TeX allows to do `\openin` of non-existed file, but it returns true when `\ifeof` is used before first `\read`. On the other hand, if the file exists and it is empty, then first `\ifeof` returns false, first `\read` defines empty macro and the `\ifeof` (used after this `\read`) returns true.

*Notice: All TeX engines since 2020 allow alternative syntax `\openin15={\filename}` which is incompatible with TeX 82 but allows to use spaces in file names.*

If you are using OpTeX then there is a macro `\isfile` for doing this task:

```
 \isfile{filename}\iffalse ...file doesn't exist...\fi
 or
 \isfile{filename}\iftrue  ...file do exist...\fi
 or
 \isfile{filename}\iftrue  ...file do exist...\else ...file doesn't exist...\fi
```

Comment: About the remark, I believe `\openin15="file name"` also work and allow spaces in file name. Not sure about the compatibility. (that having said it means `"` cannot be used in file name at all)