# color an entry in the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, color, captions

I have a command that prints an image and will be used inside a certain environment.

First I run a test if the file exists and is a valid image file
(see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99070/check-for-a-valid-file-before-using-includegraphics) for the definition of `\imagetest`).
If it is ok then the image is just printed, otherwise I print a box with an informative message.

```
\newcommand{\musicSFE}[1]{
    \imagetest{#1}
    {% If it is a valid image do:

        \noindent
        \includegraphics{#1}

    }
    {% If it isn't a valid image do:

        \bigskip
        %TODO: Make the entry in the \listof...s red
        \framebox{\colorbox{yellow}
            {Image #1 missing}}

        \bigskip
    }
}
```

So far it works ok, but I would like to also print the caption red _in the list of ...
What I found is that with

```
\captionsetup{font={color=red}}
```

I can change the appearance of the caption, but only that at the current place in the document.
If I do

```
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{mystyle}{\textcolor{red}{#1 #2}}
```

and then

```
\captionsetup{listformat=mystyle}
```

It actually changes the \listof, but only the reference number gets colored.

So the question is:
How can I color the list entry of such a floating environment?
Actually I'd also accept a suitable other way to highlight such an entry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\DeclareCaptionListFormat` code makes LaTeX write

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {\textcolor{red}{1}}{\ignorespaces This will be red\relax }}{1}
```

in the `.lof` file. Using `\color{red}#1#2` wouldn't help, because the argument of `\numberline` is typeset in a group, so the color setting doesn't propagate to the caption text.

One can use a trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\makered}{\makeredaux\aftergroup\makeredaux}
\newcommand\makeredaux{\color{red}}

\DeclareCaptionListFormat{mystyle}{\makered#1 #2}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{listformat=mystyle}
\caption{This will be red}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{This will be black}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thus the first caption will cause writing

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {\makered 1}{\ignorespaces This will be red\relax }}{1}
```

in the `.lof` file. When LaTeX typesets it, `\makered` becomes `\makeredaux` that prints the number in red, followed by `\aftergroup\makeredaux` that will be executed when the `\numberline` group is finished, that is, when LaTeX is typesetting the caption text (in the list of figures).

[image]

(Note: in the image the figures are at the top, because no positioning argument has been specified in this example document.)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. And I even think I understand what's working ;-)