# How to create Placeholder for missing figure?

Tags: floats, xetex, texlive

I'm writing my paper using `texlive2013`.As for me,it is rather annoying to swich between writing and plotting figures.So I'd like to create a `dummy figure` when I was writing to avoid disturbance and add figures back later.I found a nice solution  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44195/placeholder-for-figure-includegraphics):

[image]

However,not only were the missing figures,other normal figures were replaced as well.Is there a way to get it around?

Comment: Inside your `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` you can put something like `\rule{4cm}{8cm}`.  This could also be 'automated' using conditionals...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99070/check-for-a-valid-file-before-using-includegraphics/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A small workaround, but not perfect for sure (depending on the graphics extension, it might fail) -- I use the `\IfFileExists` in a slightly redefined `\includegraphics` command. It test for four extensions (all in lower case) (`.eps`,`.pdf`, `.jpg` and `.png`)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\let\StandardIncludeGraphics\includegraphics%
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
\IfFileExists{#2.eps}{%
  \StandardIncludeGraphics[#1]{#2}%
}{%
 \IfFileExists{#2.pdf}{%
  \StandardIncludeGraphics[#1]{#2}%
  }{ % No, no .pdf, try *.jpg 
   \IfFileExists{#2.jpg}{%
    \StandardIncludeGraphics[#1]{#2}%
    }{
      \IfFileExists{#2.png}{%
      \StandardIncludeGraphics[#1]{#2}%
      }{%
      \begin{tcolorbox}[width=6cm,height=4cm,arc=0mm,auto outer arc]
      \end{tcolorbox}
     }
   }
 }
}% 
%
}% End of command



\begin{document}



\chapter{First one}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=8cm]{some_file}
\caption{My demo figure}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

The mentioned file `some_file` does not exist at all in my paths.

[image]