# Forcing image to stay on title page

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I haven't used LaTeX for a while now, and in my document I put a image as my first page, however if I do `\newpage` and write something new, it gets moved to the first page, instead of the picture:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Bilder/Deckblatt.png}}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, you may wish to simply not use a float environment, like `figure`.

In this case, you could use:

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Deckblatt}
\end{center}
```

Note also, that it is generally best to omit your image extensions from your `\includegraphics` commands. Also, it is best to delineate graphics paths, via `\graphicspath`, and not an explicit specification. So for the above to work, you would add `\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}` somewhere in your preamble, after loading `graphicx`.

You may, however, want your figure to float, but not beyond a certain point. In that case, you can use a `\FloatBarrier`, from the [`placeins`](https://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package.

Comment: Would you mind to explain, "it is generally best to omit your image extensions from your \includegraphics commands"? :-)

Comment: ... And when I used `\graphicspath` instead of absolute paths, apparently it was taking more time to compile... :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul LaTeX's `graphicx` will generally correctly resolve the extension, selecting a good option, depending upon the TeX engine in use (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1075/134641). It is better to allow this to occur automatically, rather than specify it manually, unless one has a good reason to do so.

It is possible for `\graphicspath` to increase compilation time, but it should not be substantial and is worthwhile, IMO. This post might be useful, in this regard: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472938/134641