# \include pattern instead of filename

Tags: numbering, include, filesystem-access

I'm fairly new to LaTeX. I am using [Overleaf](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100817144901/starcraft/images/1/17/Overlord_SC2_Rend1.jpg) for my thesis, and, in order for Overleaf to display my chapters in the right order, I've prepended a number next to each of  them:

```
01-intro.tex
02-background.tex
etc.
```

Then, chapter-outline file looks like this:

```
\include{chapters/01-intro}
\include{chapters/02-background}
```

I was wondering if there was a way include a pattern instead of a filename. Something like:

```
\include{chapters/*-intro}
\include{chapters/*-background}
```

So if I change the number in the filename, the include will still work. Is there an existing command to do this? Not super important. Just curious. [The documentation I've found](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_157.html) doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: TeX in general can't search the filesystem without knowing the file name (unless you use the `--shell-escape` flag, or if you use LuaTeX, in which case something can be implemented)

Comment: This looks relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98203/can-i-test-if-a-file-exists

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just remove the numbers from the file names if you're worried, the manually added numbers won't match the chapter numbers LaTeX assigns?

Comment: Yes of course. But then Overleaf displays them in alphabetical order which is a tad less user friendly while I'm writing. I'm pretty new to LaTeX so I am just curious if there is an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you wite `\tryinput{prefix*-name}` then TeX will try to input file `prefix01-name.tex` or `prefix02-name.tex` or `prefix03-name.tex` or ... or `prefix99-name.tex`. First file which exists with such a name wins and it is read. If none such files exist then nothing is read.

You can define `\tryinput` macro by following code:

```
\newcount\tmpnum

\def\thetmpnum{\ifnum\tmpnum<9 0\fi\the\tmpnum}

\def\tryinput#1{\tryinputA#1\relax}
\def\tryinputA #1*#2\relax{
   \tmpnum=0 \let\nexti=\relax
   \loop
      \openin15=#1\thetmpnum #2
      \ifeof15 \advance\tmpnum by1
      \else \closein15 
            \edef\nexti{\noexpand\input #1\thetmpnum #2 }\tmpnum=100 \fi
      \ifnum\tmpnum <99 \repeat
   \nexti
}

%% test:

\tryinput{chapters/*-intro}
```