# Wrong file location by \IfFileExists

Tags: xetex, latex3, external-files

The following code is the content of my `main.tex`.

The file `a.tex` is in the subdirectory `tmp` under the directory where `main.tex` is, that is to say: `./main.tex` and `./tmp/a.tex`.

The problem of my code is: `\IfFileExists` find the file `./tmp/a.tex`. As there is no file `./a.tex`, I think the typeset should be `NO FILE`. But the actual typeset is `a.tex`.

Is it a problem of my version of `LaTex`, `MikTex`, `xelatex`, `auctex` or any others?

PS: the subdirctory `tmp` is used to store those tmpt and aux files during compilation.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \makeatletter
  \IfFileExists{a.tex}
  {\filename@parse{a.tex}\filename@area\filename@base.\filename@ext}
  {NO FILE}
  \makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: add \input{a.tex} and then look which file it actually find.

Comment: There is no `./a.tex`, but `./tmp/a.tex`. `\input{a.tex}` causes `./tmp/a.tex` loaded.

Comment: oh your edit explains it: such a build folder is added to the search path.

Comment: How to prevent from adding `tmp` into the search path?

Comment: you can't. latex has to find the auxiliary there. If you would remove it from the path neither the tableofcontents nor the reference would work anymore. (I never use such a build folder, imho it only make things more complicated.)

Comment: [conditionals - Can I test if a file exists? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98203/can-i-test-if-a-file-exists)

Comment: I guess the last solution there should work? Prepend `./`

Comment: Is there any way to obtain the absolute path of a file in latex by which things may get easier?

Comment: That's... a separate question? Absolute path of what file? If of current file see `currfile` package

Comment: Latex3 has file_get_full_name

Comment: @user202729 That still reflects what `TEXINPUTS` provides: here, we'd get `a.tex` as it's on the search path

Comment: `the absolute path` I mean is like `/...../....../a.tex`(from root path)

Comment: What's that reply for? I don't get it

Comment: @user202729 macros from Latex3 for `full_name` seem not output the absolute path(I mean from root path).

Answer (score 3):

`\IfFileExists` tests "would `\input` work".

So as you say you have configured things so `\input{a.tex}` inputs a file, then the test is true.

It is not normally desirable (or possible) to know where in the input path the file is located. For example this test allows LaTeX to detect a missing package with `\usepackage{mistake}` but a working example such as `\usepackage{longtable}` works portably even though the absolute file path to `longtable.sty` is system dependent

Comment: Does that parentheses mean "it's not normally possible" or absolute "it's not possible"? ■ Side note, what about with LuaTeX powers?

Comment: @user202729 well you could use `kpsewhich` (which you can use without `--shell-escape` i most configurations)  to get the full path.

Comment: For reference, OP asked a new question on how to get the absolute path → https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650955/250119