# How to insert a blank page after an included PDF only if this PDF is present in the directory?

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, multiple-files

I have multiple PDF files(that have only one page) that I need to include into a document. I succeeded in making Latex include the PDFs that are present in the directory with this:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true]{1.pdf} 

\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true]{2.pdf} 

\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true]{3.pdf} 

\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true]{4.pdf} 

\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true]{5.pdf}
```

etc...

So if only files 1.pdf and 2.pdf are present in the directory , files 3.pdf, 4.pdf etc... will be skipped and the document will continue on to the next command. Then if I have more files to include , LaTeX will automatically detect them and insert them into the final document. Which is what I want.
The problem is that I have to include a blank page between each of the inserted PDFs. I tried :

```
\includepdf[pages={1,{}},fitpaper=true]{1.pdf}
```

and this:

```
\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true]{1.pdf} 
\newpage
 \thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
```

But if I do this , it will insert a blankpage after each PDF that isn't in the directory.Thus resulting in a \AM@currentdoc... page followed by a blank page in the created PDF document.
So to be clear,I want him to only insert a blank page if the PDF file is found. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39982/use-default-figure-if-file-is-missing help?

Comment: You can check for \ifoddpage.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please complete your code to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). If you say `\includepdf[]{something.pdf}` and `something.pdf` does not exist, TeX stops with an error. It doesn't just move on to the next file. So you cannot have told us what you are really doing.

Comment: It does move on if you put a space in between both commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this which does not produce errors when a file does not exist. On my machine, I get a four page document (files 1 and 4 exist; files 2 and 3 do not).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdfset{pages=1, fitpaper=true}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*\ifpdfexists[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1.pdf}{\includepdf{#1}\cleardoublepage}{\relax}}

\begin{document}

  \ifpdfexists{body}
  \ifpdfexists{1}
  \ifpdfexists{2}
  \ifpdfexists{mypages}

\end{document}
```