# Use default message if file is missing

Tags: graphics, conditionals, include

[There](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39982/use-default-figure-if-file-is-missing) is very simple and fool-proof solution for default actions if included file is missing. It is using

```
\IfFileExists{IncludedFile}%
{% routine if file exists
}%
{% routine if file does not exist
}
```

Question is, how to make it work with directory tree. I have my images organised in several directories and I'm using `\graphicspath` command to simplify the figure including.

Comment: Why can't you use Werner's solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39987/15925 to the other question?

Comment: I don't want to redefine behaviour of all `\includegraphics` commands in the file, just in part, which is automatically generated from different data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the file input tests use `\input@path` as well as the standard TEXINPUTS variable, personally I find it easier to just set TEXINPUTS rather than use `\input@path` (`\graphicspath` just sets a version of `\input@path` used locally
during the scope of `\includegraphics`)

However if you want to use the macro directory list for all such operations, replace

```
\graphicspath{{dir1}{dir2}}
```

by

```
\makeatletter\def\input@path{{dir1}{dir2}}\makeatother
```

and all latex file input commands should use that path.

Comment: How to change the TEXINPUTS? Changing `\graphicspath` doesnt work, or the `dir1` must be absolute path, not relative?

Comment: @Crowley changing `\input@path` will work (set it before loading graphics package)  _all_ it does is set `\input@path` locally, setting TEXINPUTS can be done in your texmf.cnf file or in most command lines just done on the commandline for example `TEXINPUTS.//: pdflatex file` will make `\input{chapter1}` find `chapter1.tex` in any directory recursivelu under the current directory, or anywhere on the standard input path.

Comment: Yes, I was changing `\input@path` after calling `graphicx` package. Now it works as it should work. Thank You.